# Is there a way to have multiple phpt tests in one file?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpt

Is there a way to have multiple blocks of

```
--TEST--
...
--FILE--
...
--EXPECT--
...
```

in one phpt file?

Like this:

```
--TEST--
...
--FILE--
...
--EXPECT--
...

--TEST--
...
--FILE--
...
--EXPECT--
...
```

I found instructions and examples to have many lines of output tested  under a single --EXPECT--, but that's not the same:

http://qa.php.net/sample_tests/sample001.php

Comment: What do you mean by "tests", and when you say "file", do you mean in the php file?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I updated the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented [here](http://qa.php.net/phpt_details.php), it is not possible to have several PHPT tests in one PHPT file.

You should really have a look to [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit) or [Atoum](https://github.com/mageekguy/atoum) if you're willing to unit-test a web applciation.

Comment: Thank you. I knwo what can be done with testing frameeworks. I was interested in PHPT.